# How to display fixed width values in doublespinbox

Tags: qt

I have 4 doublespinboxes in my Window. I want to display the values of fixed width in this doublespinbox. For e.g my doublespinbox range is 0 to 100.00 I want to display the values in the format of 000.00 always.So though the value is 8 it should get displayed as 008.00 in my doublespinbox . Similarly I want highlight each digit in my doublespinbox during editing the values . How can I do the same? . The width/range varies for all the spinboxes. Can somebody help me.

Comment: Can you add some more information?  What have you tried?

Comment: `QDoubleSpinBox` already has the ability to force trailing zeroes (using the `decimals` property), but why would you want leading zeroes? "I want highlight each digit in my doublespinbox during editing the values" You will have to clarify what you mean by that.

Comment: I want the functionality of leading zeros because of application need and I can not avoid this.Using set decimals I can set 2 decimals after "." but how can I add leading zeros? I want to highlight the selected digit during editing i.e functionality same as that of setInputMask that we use for lineedit.

Answer (score 1):

As I've said in comment to @asclepix post you need to reimplement `textFromValue`. This snippet works fine for me.

```
class MyDoubleSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
public:
    explicit MyDoubleSpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent) {
        setMaximum(999.99);
    }

    QString textFromValue(double val) const {
        const int width = 6;        // length of whole number in symbols '000.00'
        const int precision = 2;    // after separator

        // rightJustified to add leading zeroes
        return QLocale().toString(val, 'f', precision).rightJustified(width, '0');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was really helpful. I have taken custom spinbox as mentioned by you and made the changes as mentioned above and it worked fine for mask of 000.00 but I have one more query how can I change the width and precision every time as per my need.

Comment: @Poonam make width and precision members of `MyDoubleSpinBox` and provide setters to change them.

Comment: Is it neccesory to reimplement valurFromText also if I reimplement textFromValue function?

Comment: @Poonam no, it is not necessary especially in your case

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to use setDecimals to to force the trailing zeros and setPrefix for the leading ones. The problem is that you have to change the prefix depending on the value of the doublespinbox. The simple way is to connect a slot to the valueChanged signal and do the job there. The less simple way is to subclass the doublespinBox, but I don't know what to reimplement.

Comment: class `QDoubleSpinBox` has `textFromValue` and `valueFromText` virtual functions. I think it should be enough in order to get wanted result.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. Both of them displays values only w/o leading zeroes. For e.g If I want to display 011.11 then textFromValue will display 11.11 only it will remove the zeroes on its own.

Comment: @Poonam I posted example in answer.